# Using java based regular expression to query Oracle

Tags: java, regex, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I have to write a query where a regular expression which is java based (i believe POSIX standard) is to send to a stored procedure. Which will use this regex string to query database to fetch only those records which statisfy the regex.

I was reading about [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/oracle.html) and i saw that oracle regular expression's aren't same as Java i.e.

> With version 10g, Oracle Database offers 4 regexp functions that you
>   can use in SQL and PL/SQL statements. These functions implement the
>   POSIX Extended Regular Expressions (ERE) standard. Oracle fully
>   supports collating sequences and equivalence classes in bracket
>   expressions. The NLS_SORT setting determines the POSIX locale used,
>   which determines the available collating sequences and equivalence
>   classes.
>
> Oracle does not implement the POSIX ERE standard exactly, however. It
>   deviates in three areas. First, Oracle supports the backreferences \1
>   through \9 in the regular expression. The POSIX ERE standard does not
>   support these, even though POSIX BRE does. In a fully compliant
>   engine, \1 through \9 would be illegal. The POSIX standard states it
>   is illegal to escape a character that is not a metacharacter with a
>   backslash. Oracle allows this, and simply ignores the backslash. E.g.
>   \z is identical to z in Oracle. The result is that all POSIX ERE
>   regular expressions can be used with Oracle, but some regular
>   expressions that work in Oracle may cause an error in a fully
>   POSIX-compliant engine. Obviously, if you only work with Oracle, these
>   differences are irrelevant.
>
> The third difference is more subtle. It won't cause any errors, but
>   may result in different matches. As I explained in the topic about the
>   POSIX standard, it requires the regex engine to return the longest
>   match in case of alternation. Oracle's engine does not do this. It is
>   a traditional NFA engine, like all non-POSIX regex flavors discussed
>   on this website.
>
> If you've worked with regular expressions in other programming
>   languages, be aware that POSIX does not support non-printable
>   character escapes like \t for a tab or \n for a newline. You can use
>   these with a POSIX engine in a programming language like C++, because
>   the C++ compiler will interpret the \t and \n in string constants. In
>   SQL statements, you'll need to type an actual tab or line break in the
>   string with your regular expression to make it match a tab or line
>   break. Oracle's regex engine will interpret the string '\t' as the
>   regex t when passed as the regexp parameter.

Just wondering if there is some sort of help that i can use to tackle this issue? Or do i have to transfer Java regex into PLSQL regex?

The regex which we are going to use is going to be used widely within Java. There are few usecases where the same regex would be applied to oracle Stored Procedures. One of the sample **regex** is `.*__.*__^ABC`

I believe, it would be way more helpful if i can know what are incompatibilities in these 2 versions :)

Comment: As your quote explains, it depends on the regex - some regexes will work in both implementations. Can you show us your regex? What have yuo tried so far?

Comment: `is to send to a stored procedure`

Why do you have to do this? It's trivial to write an [oracle-compatible regex](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm).

Comment: If a regex is executed by a PL/SQL stored procedure then it should be an Oracle regex, shouldn't it ? From Java point of view the regex is just a plain string that is passed to Oracle. There should be no reason to make any regex conversion.

Answer (score 1):

First, gather all used/expected regular expressions and run a few queries on a sample/test table to see if there are any regexps that work in Java, but not in Oracle. Maybe there will be no problems at all as Oracle documentation says that it supports the POSIX and Unicode standards for regexps, and it enhances them.

In case you find regexps that do not work in Oracle, then you can consider developing a Java stored procedure with a PL/SQL wrapper and use that in your queries. Then definitely there will be no problem.

Comment: the regex are unknown atm .. it could be anything.

Comment: In this case I would start with the assumption that there will be no issues and develop a simple query that uses the regexps as it gets them. I guess, you will have a QA phase in the PDLC; you will find out then if there will be any tricky regexp that Oracle interprets differently. In the meantime I would play with regexps to see if I can find differences. Plus, I would tell the project manager or business stakeholders to get/produce a use cases document as a developer cannot work properly without proper requirement specifications...